# Require exact match from /address/structured OR reliable filter

Tags: azure-maps

My use case is simple; I have a country code and a postal code. I want lat/lon back. Take the following query:

[https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?subscription-key={key}&api-version=1.0&postalCode=Thomas&countryCode=US](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?subscription-key=%7Bkey%7D&api-version=1.0&postalCode=Thomas&countryCode=US)

This returns 5986 results, the first of which is a hit for Thomas, OK. I provided a `postalCode` explicitly, so I'm not sure why a fuzzy search is being performed (what's the point of structured anyway?). On top of that, I see no reliable way to filter this result out as incorrect. I noticed the `fuzzyLevel` field in the `summary` section and thought I could perhaps use that. Unfortunately, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured#searchaddressstructuredsummary) (useless autogenerated nonsense) have this to say about it:

```
fuzzyLevel    integer    FuzzyLevel property
```

Well that's certainly helpful. I played around with it but, unfortunately, the query above comes back with `fuzzyLevel: 1`, the same as an "exact" match. Using the postalCode "error" returns a 2, so that can be filtered, but not universally helpful. I also noticed that there is no `postalCode` included in the `address` result for `postalCode: Thomas`. I of course have no idea if I can count on this behavior though, so I am hesitant to rely upon it. Is there a simple way I can request that only an exact match on the field(s) I provide be used, otherwise return nothing? I have no use for these wild guesses.

I considered filtering by `result.entityType == 'PostalCodeArea'`, but entityType is not returned for all results (e.g. E6L 2H2, CA. E6L alone would work, but that's not what we have coming in.)  So now I'm at `result.entityType == 'PostalCodeArea' || result.address.postalCode != null`, which just seems awful.

Comment: Related Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89612/index.html

Answer (score -1):

**Updated:** 09/10/2020: PDT:
The answer is **'No'**.

---

Below is the response from the Microsoft Product Group Team, I hope this helps with your query.Similar discussion is posted on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89612/index.html)

> We will only return error codes when the query is invalid, e.g. it has
> invalid parameters, or it does not follow the correct format.
>
> Azure Maps Search services are designed to return coordinate location
> for a given address excluding the unit level, and they can be used for
> address validation.
>
> Azure Maps can provide an address that has spelling mistakes removed.
> The returned data follows the standard format for the specific
> country, e.g. in the US and in Finland we have different formats.
>
> Our Geocoder API’s do provide a list of addresses in the response, but
> this will require some human intervention to choose which of these
> response makes the most sense. This works well in forms where the
> customer can choose the right address.

**For example,** if we provide **1, Main Street, Seattle** – it will return **2 responses**:

1, Main Street, N Seattle

**and**

1, Main Street, S Seattle.

> We cannot guarantee the results if inaccurate input parameters are
> sent to us. In the example, the result type is now municipality, and
> for municipalities, we don't return postal codes, because one
> municipality can cover hundreds of postal codes.

Please let us know if you need further help in this matter.

Comment: Sorry, but this really doesn't answer the question. I'm assuming the answer is "no".

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused over this issue. I will confirm if it is 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: I confirm the Answer is **'No'**